# Can't find $\lim_{x\to-1} \frac{\sqrt[3]{1+2x}+1}{\sqrt{2+x} + x}$

Tags: limits

I'm trying to solve this limit. Wolfram showed, that there's no limit, but I can clearly see that the limit exists from graph. Tried L'Hopital's rule, but didn't get any further.
$$\lim_{x\to-1} \frac{\sqrt[3]{1+2x}+1}{\sqrt{2+x} + x}$$
I don't know which method should I use

Comment: what limit do you see on the graph?

Comment: @RushabhMehta, I made graph in google, so I can't say exactly, but it's around 0.4

Comment: Could you link the graph in the comments? I am intrigued

Comment: @RushabhMehta, it should show https://www.google.com/search?q=((1%2B2x)%5E(1%2F3)%2B1)%2F(sqrt(2%2Bx)%2Bx)&pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr

Comment: Well, Google is being really weird I guess. That's not even close to the actual graph of the function. [This](https://imgur.com/a/wOMPA1V) is closer.

Comment: Wolfram is working in the complex and tries another branch, which leads to a different limit. You can be successful with a little trick: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x+to+-1+of+(-(-1-2x)%5E(1%2F3)%2B1)%2F(sqrt(2%2Bx)%2Bx)

Comment: What is wrong with L'Hospital ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, yeah, you are right, I just miscalculated a little bit, that’s why I didn’t get an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $x=-1+h\;$ ($h\to 0$) and use the binomial approximation:

- $\sqrt[3]{1+2(-1+h)}+1=1-\sqrt[3]{1-2h}=1-\bigl(1-\frac23 h+o(h)\bigl)=\frac23 h+o(h)$,
- $\sqrt{2+(-1+h)}-1+h=\sqrt{1+h}-1+h=1+\frac12h+o(h)-1+h=\frac32h+o(h),$
  so $\;\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{1+2x}+1}{\sqrt{2+x} + x}=\dfrac{\frac23 h+o(h)}{\frac32h+o(h)})=\dfrac{\frac23+o(1)}{\frac32+o(1)}=\dfrac49+o(1).$

Answer (score 5):

Recall the formulas:
$$
\begin{align}
a^2 -b^2 &= (a - b)(a + b)\\
a^3 + b^3 &= (a + b)(a^2 - ab + b^2)
\end{align}
$$
Using them we can get the following:
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt[3]{1+2x} + 1 &=
\frac{1 + 2x + 1}{{\sqrt[3]{1+2x}}^2 - \sqrt[3]{1+2x} + 1} = 
\frac{2(x + 1)}{{\sqrt[3]{1+2x}}^2 - \sqrt[3]{1+2x} + 1} \\
\sqrt{2+x} + x &= 
\frac{2 + x - x^2}{\sqrt{2+x} - x} =
-\frac{(x + 1)(x - 2)}{\sqrt{2+x} - x}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, your limit is equal to
$$
\lim_{x\to{-1}} \frac{\sqrt[3]{1+2x}+1}{\sqrt{2+x} + x} =
\lim_{x\to{-1}} -\frac{2(\sqrt{2+x} - x)}{(x - 2)({\sqrt[3]{1+2x}}^2 - \sqrt[3]{1+2x} + 1)},
$$
which is pretty straightforward to compute.

Comment: That's beautiful

Answer (score 3):

L'Hospital works:

$$\lim_{x\to{-1}} \frac{\sqrt[3]{1+2x}+1}{\sqrt{2+x} + x}=\lim_{x\to{-1}} \frac{\dfrac2{3(\sqrt[3]{1+2x})^2}}{\dfrac1{2\sqrt{2+x}} + 1}=\frac49.$$